# Slider animation in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created this text slider.

Right now it scrolls all the way back when reaches the end.

Is there a way to play it smoothly in a continuous loop without resetting to initial position?

```js
let h = document.querySelector("h1 > span > span").offsetHeight;
document.querySelector("h1 > span").style.height = h + "px";

let i = 0,
  t = document.querySelector("h1 > span").childElementCount;

setInterval(function() {
  i = i < t - 1 ? i + 1 : 0;
  document.querySelector("h1 > span > span").style.marginTop = -(h * i) + "px";
}, 1000);
```

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

h1>span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1>span>span {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  We are&nbsp;
  <span>
    <span>Premium</span>
    <span>Transparent</span>
    <span>Focused</span>
  </span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a given scroll finishes, find the current topmost `<span>` (e.g. `<span>Premium</span>`), delete it, and move it to the bottom so the list now becomes:

```
<span>Transparent</span>
<span>Focused</span>
<span>Premium</span>
```

Then you can continue to just scroll to the "next" item (which is now "Transparent"). In other words, you're always scrolling up to the topmost item.

```
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    if ( ++counter > 1 ) { // Only want to swap places *after* 1st scroll:
        var elmt = document.querySelector('h1>span>span'); // 1st item
        var parent = elmt.parentNode; // Remember the parent container
        elmt.style.marginTop = ''; // reset it
        parent.removeChild(elmt); // Remove 1st child <span>
        parent.appendChild( elmt ); // Move 1st <span> to end of list
    }
    document.querySelector("h1 > span > span").style.marginTop = -(h) + "px";
}, 1000);
```

Comment: FYI I am not using jQuery. I tried as you said but no luck https://cdpn.io/e/LYpqPwy

Comment: Sorry, I saw the jQuery on @amar's answer and mistook it for your question. I'll rewrite mine in pure JS.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to your help.

Comment: For your proposed solution I think we will have to wait for CSS animation to complete `setTimeout()` before cutting first element and pasting it to the last.

Comment: @AwaisZahid See my updated answer. Just replace your `setInterval()` with mine (you'll also need to add the `var counter = 0` just above it).

Comment: It works. I liked your approach. Especially the comments are very helpful. Thank you once again. Just for the curiosity are there other possible ways to do this in native JS?

Comment: You're welcome! Since you're using native CSS animation, you're kind of relying on that for the effect, so you probably have to go with my method of continuously repositioning the elements. If you did the actual scrolling in JS you might be able to do it differently, but either way would require some sort of JS, whether native or jQuery or otherwise.